# undo preventDefault after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having some links with a class .reg_required that is making all links display a popup when the user is logged in.

```
$('.reg_required').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#login_popup').dialog('open');
});
```

after the successful login ajax I remove all the classes from the links but the behavior of showing up the login popup remains.

```
$('.reg_required').removeClass("reg_required")
```

How can I make the links go to the specified url again after the login success?

Comment: Keep in mind that users can easily manipulate the DOM and/or disable JavaScript in their own browsers. Depending on your context and the necessary level of security, you might consider an additional server-side solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegation with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.reg_required', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#login_popup').dialog('open');
});
```

I think what was happening is when you binded with `.click()` the handlers still stay attached after removing the class. This is because the handler is attached to whatever was in `$('.reg_required')` and onwards. However, the `on()` handler will be attached to **only** current and future **.reg_required**.